# Sum case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below SQL is returning 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.', can anyone help?

```
SELECT 
sum(case when Frequency = 'Monthly' then ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0.0) else 0 end) + 
sum(case when Frequency = '4 Weekly' then ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0.0) / 2 else 0 end) +
sum(case when Frequency = 'Fortnightly' then ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0.0) / 3 else 0 end) +
sum(case when Frequency = 'Weekly' then ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0.0) / 5 else 0 end) 
FROM TableWHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: don't do `sum(sum())`... the inner sum's results won't be available until the entire data set's been processed, whcih means the outer sum() can't do anything. it's chicken/egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want conditional aggregation, you only want one `sum()`:

```
SELECT sum(case when Frequency = 'Monthly' then Amount else 0 end) + 
       sum(case when Frequency = '4 Weekly' then Amount / 2 else 0 end) +
       sum(case when Frequency = 'Fortnightly' then Amount / 3 else 0 end) +
       sum(case when Frequency = 'Weekly' then Amount,0.0) / 5 else 0 end) 
FROM Table
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like

```
sum(case when Frequency = 'Monthly' then ISNULL(Amount,0.0) else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
sum(case when Frequency = 'Monthly'     then ISNULL(Amount,0.0)     else 0 end) + 
sum(case when Frequency = '4 Weekly'    then ISNULL(Amount,0.0) / 2 else 0 end) +
sum(case when Frequency = 'Fortnightly' then ISNULL(Amount,0.0) / 3 else 0 end) +
sum(case when Frequency = 'Weekly'      then ISNULL(Amount,0.0) / 5 else 0 end) 
FROM Table
WHERE Id = 1
```